# Firefox won't play iMacros via URL?

Tags: firefox, imacros

For the last week or so I've been developing an application to programmatically maintain some stuff online, to do so I need to launch iMacros from Firefox via Python.

Currently I am doing that in Python with this code, it has worked fine for a week:

```
firefoxpath = '"C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox//firefox.exe"'
macroCommand = firefoxpath + " imacros://run/?m=" + path_to_macro
subprocess.Popen(macroCommand)
```

*There is some other stuff that cleans up processes in there and listens for errors too, but all that really matters right now is launching the macros*

Today, after this worked for several hours of coding. I started getting this popup when attempting to launch via Python. (It's the popup Firefox gives when it doesn't know how to handle a file or URL).

Launch Application Popup:

[image: Launch Application Popup]

It would seem that Firefox no longer thinks it can launch imacros files directly. However, the files play just find if you click "play" in the iMacros panel.

I've been troubleshooting for an hour and it doesn't seem like anyone online has had this problem before. Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE:**

I managed to get this working by completely reinstalling windows on the problem machine. Before doing that, I reinstalled firefox a number of times, tried a portable copy of firefox, deleted firefox's registry entries, disabled multi-process windows in FF, uninstalled all plugins one by one, and tried the same thing as a different user (both with and without admin).

None of that worked, if anyone in the future encounters this bug I recommend just reinstalling windows on the problem machine.

I was using

- Windows 10
- Firefox 54
- iMacros for FF 9.0.3
- Python 2.7

God speed to anyone else who encounters this.

Comment: Why have you not just selected the one you wanted and checked the "Remember my choice for imacros links" checkbox? Are you saying that it does not work no mater which selection you make?

Comment: That is correct, no matter what selection I make it does not open. It looks like the 'imacros' selection in that box is actually the iMacros browser which I also have installed. Interestingly, it doesn't even open in the iMacros browser either.